# How to remove hash from url in Angular 9

Tags: angular

There are dozens of questions like this that relate to versions of Angular other than 9.  Since the fix seems straightforward and I believe I have implemented it I am wondering if it has changed in v9.

index.html

```
<head>
    <base href="/">
```

app-routing.module.ts

```
imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { anchorScrolling: 'enabled', useHash: false })],
```

component.html

```
<a [routerLink]="['/home']" fragment="clients" data-target="#clients"><i class="bx bx-file-blank"></i> <span> Clients</span></a>
```

URL shown in the browser:

```
https://localhost:5001/home#clients
```

Angular version:  9.1.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have set the link explicitly to do that by setting the `fragment` directive.

If you want to navigate to `#clients` but not have it show in the URL. Use `skipLocationChange`:

```html
<a [routerLink]="['/home']" fragment="clients" skipLocationChange data-target="#clients"><i class="bx bx-file-blank"></i> <span> Clients</span></a>
```

If you want the link to go to `/home/clients`. Remove the fragment directive:

```html
<a [routerLink]="['/home']" data-target="#clients"><i class="bx bx-file-blank"></i> <span> Clients</span></a>
```

https://angular.io/api/router/RouterLink

Comment: Works, thank you!  `skipLocationChange ` : not found on angular.io/docs, but appears in v2.angular.io.  Is it deprecated?

Comment: Hey @Sam it can be found in the docs for [router link directive](https://angular.io/api/router/RouterLink)