# How to remove hash from url in Angular 9 and also update the url in the browser to the current url

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular9

This question is not the same as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61509016/how-to-remove-hash-from-url-in-angular-9).

I need to know how to remove the hash from from the url and also update the url in the browser.

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { anchorScrolling: 'enabled', useHash: false, scrollPositionRestoration:'enabled' })],


"@angular/router": "~9.1.2",
```

**Current behavior:**

Url in browser: /something

User clicks:    `<a [routerLink]="['/home']" fragment="home" >Home</a>`

Browser navigates to: /home

Url in browser: /home#home

Page scrolls to: #home

**Behavior when using answer to question cited above:**

Url in browser: /something

User clicks:    `<a [routerLink]="['/home']" fragment="home" skipLocationChange>Home</a>`

Browser navigates to: /home

Url in browser: /something

Page scrolls to: #home

**Desired behavior:**

Url in browser: /something

User clicks:    `<a [routerLink]="['/home']" fragment="home" >Home</a>`

Browser navigates to: /home

Url in browser: /home    // desired behavior is that current url is shown in browser without hash.

Page scrolls to: #home

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md#question

> To save your and our time, we will systematically close all issues that are requests for general support and redirect people to Stack Overflow.

The answer to this question is:  **Don't use unsupported frameworks.**